# Converting Shapefiles

Tags: qgis

Can anybody help me on how to convert shape files into .asc files? I want to convert layers from shape files into this format but I don't know how to go about it in qgis.

Comment: do you esri elevation grids?

Comment: .ASC files are a raster format, shapefiles are a vector format. The process for converting between the two varies greatly depending on what your data is.

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways to covert shapefile to ASCII, since there is no one ASCII format.  Are you looking for something specific, or would a tab-delimited columns with well-known ASCII geometry in the last column suffice?